# Largest "drawing" of a graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph and $D$ some drawing of $G$ in the standard $\mathbb R^2$ plane. (This must be distinguished!) $D$ must fulfil two conditions:

1. A triangle $T=(V_1,V_2,V_3)$ of vertices of $G$ shall be called "forbidden" if all of its slopes between the vertices of $T$ in $D$ have the same sign.
2. Should $G$ be nonplanar, that's OK, but two crossing lines $(V_1,V_2),(V_3,V_4)$ again shall be called "forbidden" if their slopes has the same sign.

$G$ likewise shall be called forbidden if all possible $D$ contain a forbidden configuration 1 or 2. (Example: The complete graph $K_4$ is allowed, let $D$ be a tilted square with diagonals. $K_5$ is forbidden, as any $D$ will contain a forbidden configuration.)
[image: Here is a pic with allowed and forbidden configurations:]
Let $e(G),v(G)$ count the number of edges $E$ resp. vertices $V$ of a non-forbidden $G$.

Question: Given $v(G)=n$, find the maximum $e(n)$ for any non-forbidden $G$. (Sequence start: $0,1,3,6,9,13?,?,20?,??\dots$)

Hint: From the theory of binary search trees, I expect the answer to be $O(n\cdot\log n)$, with the bit-reversal permutation $B$ giving an example for any $n$. But I would be interested in non-$O$ answers -- maybe $B$ is only optimal for $n=2^m$ (for large $n$!) or not at all.

Comment: What are $S_4$, $S_5$? Are these what some of us call $K_4$, $K_5$, the complete graphs?

Comment: Yes. I edit that, and especially I edit in another condition I complete forgot (two parallel diagonals and my O(n log n) are fake news :-/